# Bitmap.createBitmap has all pixels set to 0

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to create a bitmap from an int array, but the resulting bitmap is all 0.

**Scenario**
I have an app which takes a raw image and then does some post processing on the raw image. After this processing, I am trying to save the resulting byte array as a JPEG image and here is where I am converting the array to a bitmap so that it can be saved as a JPG.

```
int [] rgbArray = getColor( returnValue ); // converts the image to an int array
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap( rgbArray, 1008, 758, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
```

But the `image` has every pixel set to 0 and the resulting Jpeg is all black. 
I wonder if you can give any pointers as to why this should be the case?

I tried printing out the various get functions from the Bitmap to see if it gives any clue.

```
Bitmap getHeight() 758
Bitmap getWidth() 1008
Bitmap describeContents() 0
Bitmap getByteCount() 3056256
Bitmap getConfig() ARGB_8888
Bitmap isRecycled() false
Bitmap isPremultiplied() true
Bitmap hasAlpha() true
Bitmap getColorSpace() sRGB IEC61966-2.1 (id=0, model=RGB)
```

I am new to android programming, so any pointers would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
If I `setPremultiplied( false );` for the Bitmap, it works fine. I guess my immediate problem is solved if i set Premultiplied to false.

Comment: What does the function getColor() do? Does it properly convert to int[]?

Comment: It does  Essentially creating an array out of RGB values `(redValue & 0xff) << 16 | (greenValue & 0xff) << 8 | (blueValue & 0xff);`  I have found that if I set `image.setPremultiplied( false );`  it works fine

Comment: And the array you get has the correct colours?

Comment: Yes, it has the right colors.

Comment: Now I realise that you are setting ARGB_8888 but getColor() returns no alpha channel. Maybe that is why with setPremultiplied works.